# C++ bound function passed to a lambda

Tags: c++, lambda, std-function

I have the below code where I am trying to print the multiplication table of 10.
I have bound the function `multiply` with two parameters `5` and `2`. I am passing the bound function to create a lambda. And then I am attempting to pass the lambda to the `for_each` loop to print the Multiplication Table. I intutively kind of know that I may be pushing it a bit too far. But I don't know the exact reason. Can someone explain.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <future>
#include <array>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::placeholders;


int multiply(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return a*b*c;
}

int main()
{
    auto f = std::bind(multiply, 5, 2, _1);

    std::function<int(int,int,int)> f1 = [f](int a){cout << "Multiplication Table (10) :" << f(a) << endl; };

    vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), f1);

    return 0;
}
```

The error that I am getting is shown below.

```
/home/karthik/Workspace/cpppen/learning/main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/home/karthik/Workspace/cpppen/learning/main.cpp:26:107: error: conversion from ‘main()::<lambda(int)>’ to non-scalar type ‘std::function<int(int, int, int)>’ requested
     std::function<int(int,int,int)> f1 = [f](int a){cout << "Multiplication Table (10) :" << f(a) << endl;};
                                                                                                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:62:0,
                 from /home/karthik/Workspace/cpppen/learning/main.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘_Funct std::for_each(_IIter, _IIter, _Funct) [with _IIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >; _Funct = std::function<int(int, int, int)>]’:
/home/karthik/Workspace/cpppen/learning/main.cpp:30:40:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:3884:5: error: no match for call to ‘(std::function<int(int, int, int)>) (int&)’
  __f(*__first);
  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/functional:58:0,
                 from /home/karthik/Workspace/cpppen/learning/main.cpp:8:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/std_function.h:701:5: note: candidate: _Res std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::operator()(_ArgTypes ...) const [with _Res = int; _ArgTypes = {int, int, int}]
     function<_Res(_ArgTypes...)>::
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: What does the type of `f1` tell you?

Comment: @Rakete1111 - It tells me that it should be passed 3 parameters. I am passing a function with two bound and one placeholder parameter.

Comment: Notice that replacing `std::function<int(int,int,int)>` by `auto` would make the code working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am passing a function with two bound and one placeholder parameter.

No you're not. Your lambda looks like this:

```
[f](int a) {
    cout << "Multiplication Table (10) :" << f(a) << endl;
}
```

That is the callable object that you are passing to `std::function`. Now, the lambda is callable with only one argument, not three. Notice:

```
[/*...*/](int a){ /*...*/ }
//        ^^^^^
//      one parameter
```

Likewise, `f` is a callable object with only one parameter. You can't call it with three arguments, because you've bound two parameters to specific values, so, for all intents and purposes, there are no three parameters. Maybe this makes it more clear:

```
auto add = [](int a, int b) { return a + b; };
auto addTo5 = [&add](int a) { return add(a, 5); };

add(1, 2); // ok, lambda takes two parameters
addTo5(3); // ok, lambda takes one parameter
addTo5(1, 2); // not ok, lambda doesn't take two parameters

std::function<int(int, int)> fadd = add; // ok
std::function<int(int)> faddTo5 = addTo5; // ok
std::function<int(int, int)> faddTo5fail = addTo5; // not ok, same reason

// addTo5 is approximately what std::bind does: It generates an object which has
// several variables "fixed", and so only takes the placeholder arguments that aren't
// specified.
```

So, the fix is to change `f1`'s type to reflect what you are actually storing; a callable that takes an `int` and returns nothing:

```
std::function<void(int)> f1 = /*...*/;
//            ^^^^
//          lambda returns nothing
```

Comment: I notice that but I don't know why c++ force to do something: std::function<int(int)> f1 = [f](int a) -> int {cout << "Multiplication Table (10) :" << f(a) << endl; };     You must explicitly mention the return type of lambda.

Comment: @Amin No you don't and you never had to AFAIK. What makes you think that?

Comment: I use Clion and writing std::bind, warning me to use lambda instead of that however if use std::bind and try to use it lambda without mention return type, it says return type is function<lambda(int)> and cant cast to function<int(int)> for function except I use auto for variable.

Comment: @Amin Hmm that's weird. I can't tell you what causes this without looking at the code though. Can you maybe link it here? Or maybe tell me/lookup the error message? Or maybe create a new question?

Comment: maybe new question is not good. I give you error: conversion from 'main()::<lambda(int)>' to non-scalar type 'std::function<int(int)>' requested

Comment: @Amin Oh ok. What's in the lambda body? Is there a `return`?

Comment: oh. I forget. thanks it is worked. it is because of c++ that doesn't force to return when need return type. :)

Comment: @PaulSanders Yikes, so true. Thanks! :)